# Can I pass all the <jvmarg> parameters to an ant junit task from a single file

Tags: junit, ant, jvm-arguments

So I have something like

```
<junit fork="true" forkmode="perTest">
   <jvmarg value="-Darg.to.pass.our.tests.one=arg1">
   <jvmarg value="-Darg.to.pass.our.tests.two=arg2">
   <jvmarg value="-Darg.to.pass.our.tests.three=arg3">
   ...
   <jvmarg value="-Darg.to.pass.our.tests.enn=argN">
</junit>
```

I know the ideal is forking once, but that's not possible for our tests for reasons I won't go into.

My question is, can I do something like:

```
<junit fork="true" forkmode="perTest">
   <jvmargs file="standard_args.properties">
</junit>
```

I'm looking for the freedom to specify different argument at test execution time.

I know I could do

```
<junit fork="true" forkmode="perTest">
   <jvmarg value="${arg.one}">
   <jvmarg value="${arg.two}">
   ...
   <jvmarg value="${arg.enn}">
</junit>
```

and I do use this method but this puts an expectation on the exact number of arguments passed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since all the properties your are passing to your tests are System properties (-Dxxx=yyy) , you should consider using a `syspropertyset` (c.f. ant documentation for [JUnit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) ):

```
<property file="standard_args.properties"/>
...
<junit fork="true" forkmode="perTest">
    <syspropertyset>
        <propertyref prefix="standard.arg"/>
    </syspropertyset>
</junit>
```

assuming that your property file `standard_args.properties` contains properties for your tests and that all those properties start with a specific pattern (i.e. `standard.arg` in the example above).